# How to solve package issues/dependencies

Tags: 14.04, package-management

**Background info**

I am trying to install [Veins](http://veins.car2x.org/tutorial/) simulation environment by following the tutorial provided by the author.

In step 1 it is required to install some packages in Linux, the tutorial suggest this commands to be executed on Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential gcc g++ bison flex perl tcl-dev tk-dev blt libxml2-dev zlib1g-dev default-jre doxygen graphviz libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 openmpi-bin libopenmpi-dev libpcap-dev autoconf automake libtool libxerces-c2-dev proj libgdal1-dev libfox-1.6-dev
```

When I execute this command, I immediately get:

```
E: Package 'proj' has no installation candidate
```

Then I remove the `proj` from the command and execute it again without `proj` in  it, next I get:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgdal1-dev : Depends: libgdal-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So, I remove `libgdal1-dev` from the command as well. And it executes file, by downloading the remaining packages.

To troubleshoot the problem with `proj` and `libdgal1-dev` I go to the `Synaptic Package Manager`.

**libgdal1-dev**

I search for `libgdal1-dev` in `Synaptic Package Manager` and I get an entry. I `Mark for Installation` and then `Synaptic Package Manager` suggests removing `libxerces-c2-dev` which is actually added via the initial command. Should I trust `Synaptic Package Manager` with this suggestion, and proceed further?

[image]

**proj**

What should I do about `proj`. There are some packages in `Synaptic Package Manager` such as `proj-bin` or `libproj-dev`. Should I install them?
I think `proj` has to do with [this](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/proj/4.8.0-2ubuntu2) and [this](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=proj)

What should I do to make sure that this simulation tool works fine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`proj` has to be installed as `libproj0`. You also need to install `libgdal-dev` package.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential gcc g++ bison flex perl tcl-dev tk-dev blt libxml2-dev zlib1g-dev default-jre doxygen graphviz libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 openmpi-bin libopenmpi-dev libpcap-dev autoconf automake libproj0 libgdal1-dev libfox-1.6-dev libgdal-dev libxerces-c-dev
```

Comment: do I need to re-compile the software after installing new packages?

Comment: executing your command, returns `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgdal-dev : Depends: libxerces-c-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
`

Comment: add `libxerces-c-dev` also to the list. I edited the answer.

Comment: after the last update to the command the Terminal returns: `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libxerces-c-dev : Conflicts: libxerces-c2-dev but 2.8.0+deb1-3build1 is to be installed
 libxerces-c2-dev : Conflicts: libxerces-c3-dev
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
`

Comment: remove `libxerces-c2-dev` package.